# AMP Кастомный элемент для выборки?

Tags: amp

Подскажите, есть ли возможность при создании amp версии страници сайта, создать элемент как на рисунке 
[image: навигация]
Иначе говоря, мне необходима некая карусель с условными кнопками - Новые| Популярные|Автоматы|Рулетки ... по нажатию на которые будет происходить пересборка списка с ссылками ? Или это из области фантастики ? Буду благодарен за элементарный пример, если это возможно

Answer (score 0):

Наверное вам может быть полезно что то похожее:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
    <title>Carousele, AMPs</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.ampproject.org/article-metadata.html">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <style amp-custom>
    .blue-box, .red-box, .green-box {
      width: 100%;
      height: 280px;
    }
    .blue-box {
      background: blue;
    }
    .green-box {
      background: green;
    }
    .red-box {
      background: red;
    }
    #custom-button .amp-carousel-button-prev {
      left: 5%;
      background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path  d="M14,7.4 L9.4,12 L14,16.6" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" /></svg>');
    }
    #custom-button .amp-carousel-button-next {
      right: 5%;
      background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path  d="M10,7.4 L14.6,12 L10,16.6" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" /></svg>');
    }
  </style>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  </head>
  <body>
    <amp-carousel height="300"
  layout="fixed-height"
  type="carousel">
  <a href=#><amp-img src="/img/image1.jpg"
    width="400"
    height="300"
                     alt="a sample image"></amp-img></a>
  <a href=#><amp-img src="/img/image2.jpg"
    width="400"
    height="300"
                     alt="another sample image"></amp-img></a>
  <a href=#><amp-img src="/img/image3.jpg"
    width="400"
    height="300"
                     alt="and another sample image"></amp-img></a>
</amp-carousel>
  </body>
</html>
```

Здесь вы можете пробовать установить тэги **а** внутри изображения также. Без картинок трудно тестировать и определиться.

Comment: В качестве картинок можно подгружать плейстхолдеры https://placeholder.com/ Но вопрос не за карусель, а именно за вывод списков по нажатию на кнопки

Comment: Ну, вы можете применить элемент title или создать стили для tooltips. Здесь непонятно что вы имеете ввиду под выражениями: "пересборка списка с ссылками" и "вывод списков".